# Python: Location of file generation is different in different instances

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

My python directory structure is as follows

```
tool
|
-->app
|   |--->__init__.py
|   |--->main.py
|
|-->reports
```

In my

```
main.py

class ReportGenerator():
    """A ReportGenerator class"""

    def __init__(self, f1, f2):
        print " > Report generation started...",
        reports_dir_path = "../reports/"
        report_file_name = "Report_" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S") + ".txt"
        f = open(reports_dir_path + report_file_name, 'w+')
        f.write("1234")
        f.close()
        print " > done!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Running: main.py..."

    report = ReportGenerator(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

    print "Done!"
else:
    print("Imported: main.py...")
```

Now, if I simply execute,

```
main.py file1 file2
```

The ReportGenerator class creates a final report at

```
tool
|
|
|-->reports
|       |--->Report_<DateTime>.txt
```

**Fine, this is what I expected.**

However, if I run as,

```
> from app import main
> main.ReportGenerator('file1', 'file2')
```

This time the report gets generated at

```
tool
|
|
|-->reports
|       |--->Report_<DateTime>.txt
reports
     |--->Report_<DateTime>.txt
```

It is creating one more directory called `reports` at the `tool` directory level and then a report is generated there.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because that's the directory you're running the interpreter from.

Answer (score 0):

Relative directories are referenced from the current working directory. If you use a different working directory then the absolute path created will be different.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that's messing you up. You shouldn't be hard-coding paths like that

```
reports_dir_path = "../reports/"
```

Instead, do

```
import os

reports_dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'reports')
```